# Googlemaps v3 groundoverlays loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3

I wrote a script to load weather 10 radar maps into an array and want to display an animation on a Google map or the last image.
My idea was to display one image and clear it after a delay, and go to the next one.
I can't figure out why the following code fails... Any guess ?

My test page : http://www.egloff.eu/rsmaptest/rsmap.php

My code :

```
function nextRadarMap() {
    // delete overlays
    deleteOverlays();
    // push the new images into an array of overlays
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        radarMap = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(images[i], boundaries, {
            clickable: false
        });
        imagesArray.push(radarMap);
    }
    // choose to display fixed or animated image  
    if (animToggle == true) {
        l = imagesArray.length;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            imagesArray[i].setMap(map);
            // erase previous image. use of modulus to foolproof when i=0
            //setTimeout( function() {imagesArray[(i+l-1)%l].setMap(null)},500);
            setTimeout(function () {
                clearOverlays()
            }, 500);
        }
    } else {
        // display most recent image
        imagesArray[0].setMap(map);
    }
}

// Removes the overlays from the map, but keeps them in the array
function clearOverlays() {
if (imagesArray) {
//   for (i in imagesArray) {
    for (i=0; i<imagesArray.length; i++) {
      imagesArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  In your online example animToggle is false. So it will only display the first image.

Comment: You probably want to do more than just clearOverlays inside the setTimeout callback function.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at my problem. You're right, animToggle is false on my test page, as the animation is not working. You can toggle it by clicking on the icon on the upper right. I'm looking for more inside the setTimeout. I display one overlay, and clear it after the 500ms, then move to the next image. At least, it is what i want to do ! ;-)

Comment: That is not what it currently does, all it does is run the clearOverlays() function, but you haven't provided that code, so we can't tell what it does (if it does anything).

Comment: OK, i added the clearOverlays function. As you can see, i first only claared the last displayed image, and then just to be sure, all the images.

Comment: OK. So how do you expect the code you wrote to display anything?  Where do you display the overlays if there is more than one?

Comment: Thanks. Is " imagesArray[i].setMap(map);" in the for loop not supposed to display one overlay after the other ? Or did i overlook something ?

Comment: No one can help ? :-((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lacking a solution to my problem, i changed my strategy and have build a animated GIF image with the set of images and displayed it in the groundOverlay. Like this :

```
radarMap = new google.maps.GroundOverlay( "./images/animatedmap.gif", boundaries,{clickable:false});
```

Works fine now and the result is what i was looking for !

Hope this helps ?